Letsencrypt gives 403 / 404 error with certificate renewal on new server
After migrating a website from an old to a new server (of the same hosting provider) which works flawlessly, I tried to renew the certificate: acme.sh --renew  -d 'www.example.com' --debug   --force to test whether it works.
Both servers run Ubuntu (the old 20.04 and the new 24.04) and Apache 2.4.58.
But I got this error:
[Sat Jun  8 14:26:43 UTC 2024] error='"error":{"type":"urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized","detail":"myvpsip: Invalid response from http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/WwDNlIzkWVMDJg5jEyTftibBWIVKIW9SeYdaqgThjeI: 404","status": 403'
[Sat Jun  8 14:26:43 UTC 2024] errordetail='myvpsip: Invalid response from http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/WwDNlIzkWVMDJg5jEyTftibBWIVKIW9SeYdaqgThjeI: 404'
[Sat Jun  8 14:26:43 UTC 2024] Invalid status, www.example.com:Verify error detail:myvpsip: Invalid response from http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/WwDNlIzkWVMDJg5jEyTftibBWIVKIW9SeYdaqgThjeI: 404
[Sat Jun  8 14:26:43 UTC 2024] Debug: get token url.
[Sat Jun  8 14:26:43 UTC 2024] GET
[Sat Jun  8 14:26:43 UTC 2024] url='http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/WwDNlIzkWVMDJg5jEyTftibBWIVKIW9SeYdaqgThjeI'
[Sat Jun  8 14:26:43 UTC 2024] timeout=1
[Sat Jun  8 14:26:43 UTC 2024] Http already initialized.
[Sat Jun  8 14:26:43 UTC 2024] _CURL='curl --silent --dump-header /root/.acme.sh/http.header  -L  --trace-ascii /tmp/tmp.ZjgYYnYMBK  -g  --connect-timeout 1'
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

This is in vhosts.conf:
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    AddType application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig  .pac
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomainfiles
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # Allow port 80 for Letsencrypt
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>

This forces redirect to https unless the url contains ''.well-known' (from Letsencrypt). I even commented this out for sure but to no avail.
And in ssl.conf:
<VirtualHost www.example.com:443>
#<VirtualHost *:443>
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
    SSLEngine on
    ServerName www.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-mydomain.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mydomain.log combined
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    AddType application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig  .pac
    # ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomainfiles
    # SSLCertificateFile    /root/.acme.sh/www.example.com/www.example.com.cer
    SSLCertificateFile    /root/.acme.sh/www.example.com/fullchain.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/.acme.sh/www.example.com/www.example.com.key
    # SSLCertificateChainFile /root/.acme.sh/www.example.com/fullchain.cer
</VirtualHost>

All files are migrated from the old to the new server and the site still works with valid certificates. But when I run the .acme.sh it goes wrong.
I opened the URL logged by acme.sh by a Tor browser to get an IP address not related to any of my whitelists :
http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/WwDNlIzkWVMDJg5jEyTftibBWIVKIW9SeYdaqgThjeI
which also issues a 404 error, which is actually correct, because at every renewal a new challenge will be created.
But Letsencrypt should create a challenge on that location ?
